# More detailed exceptions

Tags: php, pdo

I've nearly finished converting my old sql website to pdo to move to php7 and use prepared statements but im having trouble with a handful of errors.
The exceptions are not as clear as i would like, most errors point to my database class eg

```
Uncaught Exception: 2020-01-18 20:23:35 - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'username' AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-18 20:23:35')-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) < 30' at line 1 in file /home/test/public_html/backend/dbclass.php on line 39
Uncaught Exception: 2020-01-18 20:23:43 - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '86.28.135.16'', donated=0, forumbanned='no', warned='no', modcomment='', enabled' at line 1 in file /home/test/public_html/backend/dbclass.php on line 39
```

I am using a blunt singleton class this was the easiest way (i known this is not the best) and i had 1000 queries so a global static suited me to make it quicker. I would prefer not to wrap every query in try/catch to identify exceptions. Is they any function that might help like backtrace or gettrace im a novice so maybe theres a better way any help would be very appreciated

dbclass.php

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'host');
define('DB_NAME', 'db');
define('DB_USER', 'user');
define('DB_PASS', 'pass');
define('DB_CHAR', 'utf8');

class DB
{
    protected static $instance = null;
    protected function __construct() {}
    protected function __clone() {}

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            $opt  = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => FALSE,
            );
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
    }

    public static function run($sql, $args = [])
    {
        if (!$args)
        {
            return self::instance()->query($sql);
        }
        $stmt = self::instance()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

exception_handler

```
function handleUncaughtException($e){
    // Show general page to public
    header("Location: exceptionerror.php"); 
    // Construct the error string
    $error = "Uncaught Exception: " . $message = date("Y-m-d H:i:s - ");
    $error .= $e->getMessage() . " in file " . $e->getFile() . " on line " . $e->getLine() . "\n";

    // Log details of error in a file
    error_log($error, 3, "error_log.txt");
}
// Register custom exception handler
set_exception_handler("handleUncaughtException");
```

example of query

```
$stmt = DB::run("SELECT word FROM censor ORDER BY word");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
```

Comment: The code you posted does not support the error messages.

Comment: So, can I clarify the question being asked: you want to have MORE details about what is wrong in your queries? If so, I'm not sure that's possible - the error message is as detailed as possible already. If you need to see more of the stack trace, then try this article https://www.scalyr.com/blog/php-stack-trace-understanding-debug/

Comment: That's correct I'd like to see what goes wrong just before the error occurs, but I would prefer not to use a service

Comment: Instead of the error saying dbclass it would help if it pointed to the php page like staff.php etc